# How can I query for all children posts regardless of parent

Tags: query-posts

How can I get all children posts regardless of parent.

If you require more info:

> The setup I have is like this: I have
>   a custom post type "Project". I will
>   create top level pages as the "main"
>   project page. Then I will have
>   children pages as something like a
>   project blog. Mainly for WIP posts.
>
> I will have a Portfolio page that
>   shows all completed projects, and a
>   "WIP" page showing all WIP posts
>   regardless of project. How can I do
>   this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of possible ways.

1. Use [`get_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) with `parent => 0` to fetch top-level ones and put them as [`post__not_in`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) in query.
2. Filter [`posts_where`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) to add `AND post_parent > 0` when necessary.